# custom product variant design

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

I'm building a custom eCommerce solution for a client. I came up with this database design:

```
+---------------+     +---------------+
| PRODUCTS      |-----<     SKUS      |
+---------------+     +---------------+
|      id       |     |      id       |
|     name      |     |  product_id   |
+---------------+     |      sku      |
        |             |     price     |
        |             |      qty      |
        |             +---------------+
        |                     |
+-------^-------+      +------^------+
| VARIANTS      |------< SKU_VALUES  |
+---------------+      +-------------+
|       id      |      |      id     |
|  product_id   |      | product_id  |
|     name      |      | variant_id  |
+---------------+      |variant_option_id   |
        |              |    sku_id   |
        |              +------v------+
+-------^-------+             |
|VARIANT_OPTIONS|-------------+
+---------------+
|      id       |
|  product_id   |
|  variant_id   |
|     name      |
+---------------+
```

variants and its options are dynamically added by the admin. So for example lets say we have a T-shirt it can have many colors and sizes. Example

```
T-shirt :color=red,blue :size=small,large
```

This is would be represented in the database like so:

```
products:
 ------------------
|  id  |    name   |
 ------------------
|  1   |  t-shirt  | 
 ------------------

variants:
 ------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  name  |
 ------------------------------
|  1   |      1       |  size  |
 ------------------------------
|  2   |      1       |  color |
 ----------------------------

variant_options:
 ---------------------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  variant_id  |  name  |
---------------------------------------------
|  1   |      1       |      1       |  small |
---------------------------------------------
|  2   |      1       |      1       |  large |
----------------------------------------------
|  3   |      1       |      2       |  red |
---------------------------------------------
|  4   |      1       |      2       |  blue |
----------------------------------------------

skus:
 -----------------------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  sku  |  price  |  qty  |
------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      1       | 4xx01 |  140    |   5   |
------------------------------------------------
|  2   |      1       | 4xx02 |  140    |   10  |
------------------------------------------------
|  3   |      1       | 4xx03 |  160    |   8   |
------------------------------------------------
|  4   |      1       | 4xx04 |  160    |   15  |

sku_values:
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  product_id  |  variant_id  |  variant_option_id  |  skud_id  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      1       |       1      |         1           |      1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |      1       |       2      |         3           |      1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3   |      1       |       1      |         1           |      2    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4   |      1       |       2      |         4           |      2    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5   |      1       |       1      |         2           |      3    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  6   |      1       |       2      |         3           |      3    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  7   |      1       |       1      |         2           |      4    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  8   |      1       |       2      |         4           |      3    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What do you guys think of this implementation? is there a better way? The main thing that I see as an issue is when I need to select the specific product so for example if a user selects the `large red t-shirt` this would be my retrieval process:

I would go to the sku_values table

```
select sku_id from sku_values where product__id = 1 and variant_id = 1 and variant_option_id = 2; returns  3,4
select sku_id from sku_values where product_id = 1 and variant_id = 2 and variant_option_id = 3; returns  1,3

now i know the sku_id I need is 33
```

That to me doesn't feel very efficient; however I can't think of anything better and I've been at this for a few days.